# Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"

Tags: symfony1, sfguard

I'm having a weird problem with my symfony backend. I can log in once, but after that I get

Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"

Also, when I do login and try to edit a record from any module, I get

Fatal error: Call to a member function setLabel() on a non-object in plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasesfGuardUserAdminForm.class.php on line 28

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to delete all SFGuard Forms from lib/form/doctrine/base and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling did not help me. After all, this is a new install.

I had to modify the lines in /plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasesfGuardUserAdminForm.class

```
    //Fatal error: Call to a member function setLabel()
    if(isset($this->widgetSchema['groups_list'])) 
    {
      $this->widgetSchema['groups_list']->setLabel('Groups');
    }

    if (isset($this->widgetSchema['permissions_list'])) 
    {
    $this->widgetSchema['permissions_list']->setLabel('Permissions');
    }
```

in order to get to the next error
 of

Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"